# Send 2 different emails using 'function sendMail()'

Tags: javascript, php, email, sendmail

I have a site with some data to be chosen by users. Depending on choice, I would like to send an email.
Therefore I have 2 buttons: The first should send some data to one email, the other one should send some other data to another email.

I use this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

    function sendMail() {
        var link = "mailto:XX@YYY.com"+"&subject=" +('text. ')+ escape(document.getElementById('beregnet').value) +(',- xxx ')
                 + "&Body=" +('text bla bla bla ')
        ;

        window.location.href = link;
    }

</script>

<button onclick="sendMail(); return false" class="inputtext">Send</button>
```

But I would like to have 2 send mail buttons. Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Comment: just add a second button calling a `sendmail2()` method

Comment: thanks, now it works, i did try it ealier today but then it did not work, o)

Comment: @bwright add an anwser with your comment ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a second button like:

```
<button onclick="sendMail2(); return false" class="inputtext">Send 2</button>
```

calling `sendMail2()`. Then define a second JavaScript method like your first one:

```
function sendMail2() {
    ....
}
```